# Laravel second task schedule never runs

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

i have cron entry at shared hosting:

*** * * * * php web/artisan schedule:run**

The problem is that *queue:work* command works no matter the order, but second task (Closure) that updates video views never runs.

Code from **Kernel.php:**

```
  /**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

    //Each Video total_video_views will be accurately updated on daily basis.
    $schedule->call(function () {
       $videos = Video::get();
       app('queue')->pushOn('high', new UpdateVideoViews($videos));

    })->hourlyAt('30')
      ->name('updates all video views')
      ->withoutOverlapping();

    //this is alternative to supervisor since shared hosting someties doesnt provide supervisor
    //so we use cron instead to keep queue worker up
    $schedule->command('queue:work --queue=high,default')
        ->everyMinute()
        ->name('keeps queue worker active')
        ->withoutOverlapping();

}
```

Is there any way to run it? My suspiction is that queue:work command along "withoutOverlapping()" is kinda maybe blocking any other tasks to process.

Comment: Take `$videos = Videos::get()` outside of the callback function. Then check.

Comment: I've created individual Command for dispatching UpdateVideoViews on queue, so it's in the handle() method now, but didn't help